# I want to hide location bar, search bar, sell button except logo from PostAd.js page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firebase

I want to hide the location bar, search bar, and sell button except for the logo from the PostAd.js page. The only logo should appear on the PostAd.js page. I have posted my code for reference. I just want to show the logo on my PostAd.js page. I'm new and learning React.js

See image for reference:

[image: See image for reference]

**Header.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function Logo() {
            return (
                <a className="navbar-brand logo" href="#">
                    <img src={require("../ui/logo.png")} />
                </a>
            );
    }
    
    function SearchAndLocation(props) {
            return (
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    
                <ul className="navbar-nav flex-2 pr-3">
                    <li className="input-group input-group-lg location mr-4 flex-1">
                        <div className="input-group-btn">
                            <button className="fas fa-search search-ico"></button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Pakistan" />
                        <div className="input-group-btn">
                            <button className="fas fa-chevron-down ico"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li className="input-group input-group-lg search flex-2">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Find Mobile, Car ,laptop" />
                        <div className="input-group-btn">
                            <button className="fas fa-search ico"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <h6 className="mr-sm-2 login" >Login</h6>
                    <button className="my-2 my-sm-0 fas fa-plus sell">&nbsp;<Link to={"/postad"}>SELL</Link></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            );
    }
    
    
    
    function Header() {
            return (
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <Logo />
                    <SearchAndLocation />
                </nav>
            );
    }
    
    export {
        Header,
        Logo,
        SearchAndLocation
    };
```

**PostAd.js**

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Header } from "../components/Header";
        
        function PostAd() {
            return (
                <Header></Header>
            );
        }
        
        export default PostAd;
```

**router.js**

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import PostAd from "../components/PostAd";


class AppRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Route exact path='/postad' component={PostAd} />
        </Router>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: i mean... have you considered not returning the things you don't want rendered?

Answer (score 0):

The basic of react is composing components like lego blocks. If you don't want it on the screen, you can delete the component.

What you need to do:
Delete the SearchAndLocation component from the Header component.

Do this:

```
function Header() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <Logo />
                <SearchAndLocation />     <--- delete this line
            </nav>
        );
}
```

**If you want to hide it only in PostAd, then you have 2 solutions:**

A. Create new Header specific to be used in PostAd.

B. Create the Header so that it can read the route, and if it is currently in "/postad", you hide the "SearchAndLocation" component.

I think solution A is simpler, let's go with it. What you should do:

1. Create new header component, for example name it NewHeader. The content should be the same like Header but without "SearchAndLocation".
2. Export the NewHeader. Use the NewHeader in PostAd component.
3. Done!

For solution B, what you should do:

1. In the Header component, use useLocation hooks provided by 'react-router-dom' (I'm assuming you are using it)
2. Read the path provided by the useLocation.
3. Create an if-else render logic. If path===/postad, don't render the "SearchAndLocation" component. Else, render it.
4. Done!

Comment: When i delete this line it hides location bar, search bar from all pages. I just want to hide this components on some pages like PostAd.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering by creating variable and set it to false/true so you can hide/display  component with &&

```
function Header() {
        const showSearchBar = false
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <Logo />
                {showSearchBar &&
                    <SearchAndLocation />
                }
            </nav>
        );
}
```

Comment: It works only on current page. Read my question. It doesn't hide from PostAd.js page